# Obtener el valor de un atributo según la imagen seleccionada

Tags: php, html, php5

Tengo 3 imágenes, cada una de ellas dentro de un link

```
<a href="contratar.php?plan=basico" value="basico"><img src="images/p1.gif"></a>
<a href="contratar.php?plan=avanzado" value="avanzado"><img src="images/p2.gif"></a>
<a href="contratar.php?plan=profesional" value="profesional"><img src="images/p3.gif"></a>
```

Al hacer click en cualquiera de ellas me lleva a mi pagina **contratar.php** y aquí necesito mostrar el plan que el usuario selecciono.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sí se le envía por _get_ el tipo de plan , debe recibir ese valor con `$_GET['plan']` desde _contratar.php_ , en que se relacionan las imágenes ?

Comment: No entiendo su pregunta pero me ha ayudado a solucionar mi problema, por alguna razón intente obtener la respuesta por POST (la cual me arrojaba error) y ni se me cruzo por la cabeza hacerlo con GET. Puede responder la pregunta asi la marco como solución.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tienes que capturar el valor que envías por **GET**, y el te va a decir cual es el plan que selecciono. Te dejo el ejemplo solo te dejo el código php por que el de html ya lo tienes:

> Código php

```
$tipo = $_GET['plan'];

if($tipo == 'basico'){

    echo "El plan seleccionado es el básico";

}elseif($tipo == 'avanzado'){

    echo "El plan seleccionado es el avanzado";

}else{

    echo "El plan seleccionado es el profesional";
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Por alguna razón intentaba obtener el valor por POST, lo cual me arrojaba error y ni se me cruzo por la cabeza usar GET. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Me alegro que le allá sido de utilidad